# Customizing Menu Quirks

Tags: civivolunteer, menu, mobile, civimobile

Certain plugins such as CiviMobile and CiviVolunteer create menu items automatically.  Unfortunately those menu items aren't managed by Administer >>> Customize Data and Screens >>> Navigation Menu.  In order to give non-admin users CiviMobile menu access - I had to add it to the menu manually - which gives non-admin users a menu - but admin users double civimobile menu items. CiviVolunteer on the other hand cannot be managed via the same menu - if I want to nest it under another category - or simply change its position - I have to recreate all the menu items.  There has to be a better way - is there?

Answer (score 3):

CiviVolunteer is adding menu items in the recommended way for Extensions.

We are looking for guidance on how to support menu customization. I did not find any in the developer docs.

If anyone knows the secret, or can point to an extension that menu customization works for... it would be a help.

Comment: Looks like its not possible at the current moment - but I am told that there will be changes to menu in future that may make it possible. More on this via chat: https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/8q5txuo8s3bo3cow66r1hzotie

Thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 0):

**CiviMobile Settings** menu item is available only for users who has **administer CiviCRM** permission.

We are adding this menu item using *hook_civicrm_navigationMenu* hook